# HTML Service App to create gdoc resumes from form input

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

I've been working on this app for my company. It basically takes input from a form hosted using HTML service and creates a formatted resume via docs with the input. The problem I'm having is this:

On my HTML form, I included a button to allow the form to add more fields (for occupation history). I wrote a for loop that iterates through all the inputs of this particular section of the form, and appends them to the google doc. When the occupation list is > 3, the script fails to write them to the doc.

When I run the logger on the list, (empHist) I see that it's seeing all the data, but it will not write all of it to the doc. Thoughts?

Here is all the code:

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('page').evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE)
      .setTitle('ResuMake Test');
  return html
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

function processForm(form) {  
  var formInput = {
    firstName:   form.canFirst,
    lastName:    form.canLast,
    sizzle:      form.sizzle,
    clinDoc:     form.clinDoc,
    stork:       form.stork,
    beacon:      form.beacon,
    anesthesia:  form.anesthesia,
    empName:     form.empName,
    empYears:    form.empYears,
    description: form.description,
    school:      form.school,
    eduYears:    form.eduYears,
    degree:      form.degree
  };

  var certs = [formInput.clinDoc, formInput.stork, formInput.beacon, formInput.anesthesia];
  var empHist = [formInput.empName, formInput.empYears, formInput.description];

  var gDoc   = DocumentApp.create("Resume for: " + formInput.firstName + " " + formInput.lastName);
  var doc    = gDoc.getBody();
  var img    = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://i.imgur.com/s6wnamr.jpg');

  var title  = {};
  var h1     = {};
  var plain  = {};

  title[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE]   = 21;

  h1[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE]      = 16; 

  plain[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE]   = 11;


  //Logo
  doc.setMarginTop(25).appendImage(img).setHeight(50).setWidth(150); 

  doc.appendParagraph(formInput.firstName + " " + formInput.lastName)
     .setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).setAttributes(title);

  //Candidate Name
  doc.appendParagraph("Candidate Summary").setAttributes(h1);

  //Sizzle
  doc.appendParagraph(formInput.sizzle).setAttributes(plain);

  //Epic Certs
  doc.appendParagraph("Epic Certifications").setAttributes(h1); 

  for (var i = 0; i < certs.length; i++) {
    if (certs[i] != null) {
      var listItem = doc.appendListItem(certs[i]).setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET).setAttributes(plain);
    }
  }

  //Employment History
  doc.appendParagraph("Employment History").setAttributes(h1);

  for (var e = 0; e  <= empHist.length + 1; e++) {
    doc.appendTable([[empHist[0][e], empHist[1][e]]]).setAttributes(h1)
       .setBorderWidth(0);
    doc.appendParagraph(empHist[2][e]).setAttributes(plain);
  }

 //Education 
 doc.appendParagraph(formInput.school + " " + formInput.eduYears).setAttributes(h1);
 doc.appendParagraph(formInput.degree).setAttributes(h1);

}
```

page.html (form)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .row  {padding: 5px;}
    .pad  {padding: 8px;}
    .body {width: 800px; height: 600px;}
</style>
<div class="container body">
    <form id="root">
        <div class="row nameRow">
            <h3>Candidate Name</h3>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="canFirst" placeholder="First Name">
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="canLast" placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row sizlRow">
            <h3>Candidate Summary</h3>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Candidate Summary" name="sizzle"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row modRow">
            <h3>Epic Modules</h3>
            <div class="col-sm-4">

                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="clinDoc" value="ClinDoc">ClinDoc
                </label>

                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="stork" value="Stork">Stork
                </label>

                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="beacon" value="Beacon">Beacon
                </label>

                <label class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="anesthesia" value="Anesthesia">Anesthesia
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row emphistRow">
            <h3>Employment History</h3>

            <div class="col-xs-6 pad">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="empName" placeholder="Employer / Org">

            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 pad">
                <input class="form-control input-sm" name="empYears"type="text" placeholder="Years">
            </div>

            <div class="container pad">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="3" placeholder="Job Description"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="addEmp" class="btn btn-default">Add Another Job</button>

        <div class="row eduRow">
            <h3>Education</h3>

            <div class="col-xs-6 pad">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="school" placeholder="School / Institution">

            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 pad">
                <input class="form-control input-sm" name="eduYears" type="text" placeholder="Years">
            </div>

            <div class="container pad">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="degree" placeholder="Degree Info"></textarea>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="google.script.run.processForm(document.getElementById('root'))">resuMake!</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" onclick="google.script.host.close()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>



<script>
google.script.run.processForm();
</script>

<?!= include("script"); ?>
```

script.html (jquery for form)

```
<script>
var orgName = '<div class="col-xs-6 pad">' +
               ' <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="empName" placeholder="Employer / Org">' +

            '</div>' +

            '<div class="col-xs-6 pad">' +
               ' <input class="form-control input-sm" name="empYears" type="text" placeholder="Years">' +
            '</div>' +

            '<div class="container pad">' +
                '<textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="3" placeholder="Job Description"></textarea>' +
           ' </div>'

$('#addEmp').click(function(){
  var addEmpButton = $(this);
  $('.emphistRow').append(orgName); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put Utilities.sleep(1000); in your employment history. Write to doc function sometimes need slow call.